# Matching of the Parameters in Vectors

Tags: java, vector

I am trying to Learn Java as I am a beginner and recently i fumbled upon Vectors and Lists in Java. This is a very simple and a basic question, but any help would be really helpful for a learner. 
I have created a vector v as shown below:

```
public vector createVector(){
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add(Path1);   //Path1 is the path of a directory
    v.add(Path2);
    return v;
}
```

I have a function in which I pass, one of the parameter is **v.get(i)**. The function is shown below:

```
for(int i=0,i<v.size(),i++){
    qlm("Write", "init",getList(),**v.get(i)**); // Function call. 
}
```

Function declaration is :

```
Void qlm(String Option, String init, List lists, **String paths**){

}
```

I am not able to match the parameter in the function call which is v.get(i) with String Paths. Please share your knowledge.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why use `Vector` in 2013? And without generics to boot. Is this some legacy code or something?

Comment: Do you want more than one path? Your question is unclear

Comment: "*I am trying to Learn Java as I am a beginner and recently i fumbled upon Vectors*" => Find a new book/website/teacher to learn the language: your code is significantly outdated (cf. fge's comment).

Comment: @fge if you know something better than Vectors, please share it. Thanks.

Comment: @assylias I do know the language, but not thoroughly. Please let me know what did you mean that the code is outdated, so that I can work on it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, `ArrayList` is pretty much the standard `List` implementation

Comment: @MohammedIrfan Vector is obsolete and you should use an ArrayList instead. And you should also use generics. For example if you need a list of Strings, you define it as `List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();` - that makes your code safer at compile time.

Comment: @assylias Thanks for providing the information. I shall surely change the code and learn more about ArrayList and Generics. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Without Generics, `v.get(i)` will always return an object. Here are two ways to resolve it:

Declare `Vector` as

```
Vector< String > v = new Vector< String > ();
```

Or do

```
v.get(i).toString();
```

But before doing `v.get(i).toString()`, null check should be performed on `v.get(i)`.

Comment: You can edit your answer instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and where you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(int i=0,i<v.size(),i++){
    qlm("Write", "init",getList(),v.get(i).toString()); // Function call. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in Java, when somebody declares a Vector they will declare it using [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). To declare a Vector that will contain strings, you would write this:

```
Vector<String> myVector = new Vector<String>();
```

Then, to get a iterate over it's values, you would do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++){
    String s = myVector.get(i); // The get() method here returns a String instead of Object
}
```

Or, because Vectors are enumerable, you could do this:

```
for(String s : myVector){
    // There is now a variable named s available in the loop that
    // will contain each element in the vector in turn. 
}
```

That being said, you really shouldn't use Vectors any more. They are pretty old, and there are better lists available in Java. I would recommend that you use an ArrayList, but they're a variety of lists available which can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) under "All known implementing classes."

To rewrite your example using generics and an ArrayList, you would do this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add(Path1);
myList.add(Path2);

for(String s : myList){
    qlm("Write", "init", getList(), s);
}
```